# How do I Hide/Unhide rows based on blanks/notblank criteria within the rows I want to affect?

Tags: excel, vba

what is wrong with this code?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If IsEmpty(Sheet5.Range("A26").Value) = True Then
        Sheet5.Rows("26:27").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf IsEmpty(Sheet5.Range("A26").Value) = False Then
        Sheet5.Rows("26:27").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code does not have a syntax problem. What error do you receive, or what it does against if you want it to do? You complicated it a little. Change, please, `ElseIf IsEmpty(Sheet5.Range("A26").Value) = False Then` with only `Else`... Does your active workbook have a `Sheet5` sheet?

Comment: No errors occur but the desired outcome is not happening.  A26 is a formula that outputs either "" or another cell's value depending on criteria i set.  I am trying to get it to hide the 26th and 27th row if the formula outputs "".

ive also tried:
autofilter,
if next/then loops

Comment: A26 is a merged cell as well and i studied up and was told I could use the worksheet code name to reference the sheet in vba. the name in excel is different than the "Sheet5" but this is the code name in the vbe projects window

Comment: Then, try please, changing `IsEmpty(Sheet5.Range("A26").Value) = True` with `Sheet5.Range("A26").Value = ""`

Comment: Makeing sure i am testing this right.  
1)I inserted the code at the end of the sheet in the vbe window for "Sheet5 (Master Letter)"
2)Then clicked save workbook before exiting vbe
3)Changed values in workbook to make the formula output ""
4) so far rows stay there and dont get hidden

Comment: @FaneDuru here is the updated code: 

'Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Sheet5.Range("A26").Value = "" Then
    Sheet5.Rows("26:27").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Else
    Sheet5.Rows("26:27").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
    
End Sub'

Comment: But, do you really have to check `Range("A26")` when something has been changed on the sheet, or the cell with changed value? Do you want hiding all the time `Rows("26:27")`, or a pair of rows starting with the changed cell row?

Comment: Yes if range("A26") = ""  then hide rows 26 and 27 completely. if a26 is not "" then don't hide the rows.

Comment: Try putting a break point on the first code line (click on the code row and press F9). If the event is triggered the code will stop there. Then press F8 to run the code line by line. Is the event triggered? Does it recognize the cell value in discussion like being empty (or not)?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try it?

```
If IsEmpty(Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("A26").Value) = True Then
    Worksheets("Sheet5").Rows("26:27").EntireRow.Hidden = True
ElseIf IsEmpty(Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("A26").Value) = False Then
    Worksheets("Sheet5").Rows("26:27").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
```

Useful link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)

Comment: did not do anything.

Comment: It works fine for me. The macro should run if any cell changes on Sheet5. Can you please check the "Sheet5" name? or rename it, change it in code too and try it again.

Comment: I did change name. to fit your format but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

Application.EnableEvents = False

If Sheet5.Range("A26").Value = "" Then
    Sheet5.Rows("26:27").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Else
    Sheet5.Rows("26:27").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
End Sub

Application.EnableEvents = True
```

I had to change

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
```

to

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
```

I needed to use calculate because the "" is created by formula therefore a calculation.

Comment: When the `Change` event is triggered, calculation is done, anyhow if it is set on `xlCalculationAutomatic`.

Comment: Thanks @Faneduru for your help! How would that look in the code?

Comment: Thanks @R.bora for your help!

Comment: I mean that the Change event should work, too. Of course, if you changed something in that worksheet... `Application.EnableEvents = False` at start and `Application.EnableEvents = True` was the trick, I think.

Comment: @FaneDuru I think the way excel is thinking here is that the "Worksheet" itself is not changing since the value that is changing is based on a formula that is unchanged. do you have to write in `xlCalculationAutomatic` somewhere to get the same result with change?

Comment: If you do not change ANYTHING in the sheet, of course, Change Event is not trigger. But, do you want to suggest that the formulas result are changed by modifications in other worksheets? Only in such a case Calculate Event can replace Change one...

Comment: That is the case here. the formula result changes because of changes in another sheet in the workbook. Cool, thank you again for talking it through with me.